# CCK migration From Drupal 6 to Drupal 7: Which tables can I delete?

Tags: entities, migrations

After migrating the CCK fields from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7, which tables can I delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the tables that are safe to be removed (if they are not removed from an update function) are the ones matching the content_* pattern, which are not used anymore in Drupal 7.